# Laravel POST JSON must be a valid string rule

Tags: javascript, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I'm using the Laravel 8 `json` rule to post JSON to my API via my front-end in Javascript. However it seems that the rule is expecting a JSON string rather than a JSON object? I've got a generic Javascript function for handing requests, and have tried various content types, I'm not sure what content type Laravel 8 is expecting for the json string...

```js
// generic function
function makeHTTPRequest (
  type = 'GET',
  url = '',
  timeout = 30000,
  payload = null,
  callback
) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.open(type, url, true)

  console.log('HERE')
  console.log(payload)

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  xhr.timeout = timeout
  xhr.ontimeout = () => {
    callback.apply({
      response: { error: true, message: `Timeout exceeded ${timeout}ms`, data: null }
    })
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.response != null) {
        callback.apply({
          response: { error: false, message: 'Success', data: xhr }
        })
      } else {
        callback.apply({
          response: { error: false, message: 'No data', data: null }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    callback.apply({
      response: { error: true, message: 'Generic error', data: null }
    })
  }


  if (type === 'POST') {
    xhr.send(payload)
    return
  }


  xhr.send()
}

// usage
const form = {
  data: {
    new: true,
    form: {
      name: 'john'
    }
  }
}

makeHTTPRequest('POST', `https://my-api.com/api/save`, 30000, JSON.stringify(data), function() {
  const res = JSON.parse(this.response.data.response)
  console.log(res) // returns validation errors because it isn't valid json??
})
```

My PHP validator is...

```php
// validation
$request_data = array_merge($request->only('data'));

$validator = Validator::make($request_data, [
    'data' => 'required|json'
]);
```

What header am I missing? The request payload when logged is a JSON object rather than a string??

Comment: You are converting the whole data in JSON string. Instead of it try  payload = { data: JSON.stringify(data)} and  then xhr.send(payload).

Comment: Tried this, it just shows up as `[object Object]`, not sure why `array_merge($request->only('data'))` isn't working...

Comment: why are you calling `array_merge` with only 1 argument?  also see what `dump($request->json())` gets you

Comment: For the purposes of my reduced test case example, I have only included one item. There are others, this isn't the original question I'm needing help with.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)` What is `data`? Do you mean `form.data`?